# keras reshape input image to work with CNN

Tags: python, keras, reshape, conv-neural-network

There are other post with similar questions but none of the answers are helping me. I´m new to this CNN world.

I followed [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/01/lenet-convolutional-neural-network-in-python/) tutorial for training a CNN with Keras using theano as BackEnd with the MNIST dataset. Now I want to pass to the CNN my own jpg image but I dont know how to reshape it. Can you help me please? Im super new at this.

So far, I tried this to reshape

```
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0) image = preprocess_input(image)
```

but get the following error when predicting:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 1, 28, 28) but got array with shape (1, 3, 28, 28)
```

As you can see, my CNN uses width = 28, height = 28 and depth =1.

Comment: hi there, did you manage to find an answer to this? I too have my own set of images to be shaped / resized to fit into keras 28, 28, 1 model. How do I get all images of various sizes to fit in 28,28,1? I am getting the below error when feeding in unprocessed image: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 21600 into shape (28,28,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Numpy for reshaping. Since, you have been using a 2D-Convolutional model:

```
 image = np.reshape(image, (28, 1, 28, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows the network expects the image shape is 1*28*28, but your input is in 3*28*28. I guess the image you input is a color image, 3 channels(RGB), while the network expects a gray image, one channel.

When you call opencv to read image, please use code below.
`img = cv2.imread(imgfile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Answer (score 0):

simply use
'''image = np.reshape(len(image), (28,28, 1))'''